# Is it mandatory to start JanusGraph server for accessing graph using HBase as backed

Tags: hbase, graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am new to JanusGraph and want to use graph database for storing and accessing connected data in distributed environment.

I want to access graph database using TinkerPop/JanusGraph Java API without adding new major component (JanusGraph Server) in my architecture

As per my understanding we need to start JanusGraph Server or Gremlin Server to access data in distributed environment.

Could anyone guide me how can I achieve this or let me know other database which can fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The [JanusGraph HBase documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/hbase.html) discusses several options:

- Local Server Mode
- Remote Server Mode
- Remote Server Mode with Gremlin Server

The first 2 options do not require a separate server. Your client application makes a direct connection to HBase. For example:

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build()
    .set("storage.backend", "hbase")
    .set("storage.hostname", "77.77.77.77, 77.77.77.78, 77.77.77.79")
    .open();
```